# 10 external Optical Disk Drive (ODD)

Tags: macos, usb, automount

I want 10 usb odd connections to my MacBook Pro. I have provided dedicated power to the drives and use a sata to usb converter cable connected to two usb bridges.

I find the disk mounts are inconsistent. When this works I have a /dev/disk2 thru /dev/disk11 with /Volume/.

I am running eset which scans each dvd prior to mounting the drive. The timing on the eset scan may be a factor.

I would like to turn off auto mount and manually script the mounting process because I have not found a means to force a mount once a disk fails to auto mount.

Comment: Are you connecting hard drives/SSDs, or DVD drives?

Comment: these are all optical dvd rw drives